# rspec receive method not working as expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, ruby-on-rails-4

I can't understand why the following code does not work in rspec when running my tests.

```
Lead.update_status(2,2,true)
expect(Lead).to receive(:update_status).with(2, 2, true)
```

I have also tried

```
Lead.update_status(2,2,true)
expect_any_instance_of(Lead).to receive(:update_status).with(2, 2, true)
```

The error I I get is

```
(<Lead(id: integer, contact_id: integer, course_presentation_id: integer, status: integer, created_by_user_id: integer, updated_by_user_id: integer, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, mailchimp_status: integer) (class)>).update_status(2, 2, true)
           expected: 1 time with arguments: (2, 2, true)
           received: 0 times with arguments: (2, 2, true)
```

Note if I add puts "test" into my code this is prints out, so I know that update_status is actually working.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You should place your expectation before the code you expect to call that method:

```
expect(Lead).to receive(:update_status).with(2, 2, true)
Lead.update_status(2,2,true)
```

Comment: Hi, can you link the rspec documentation regrading this?

Comment: @TrungDQ - https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/basics/expecting-messages#passing-positive-message-expectation

Comment: For someone who is using `rswag`, simply put this `expect` in `before(:each)` block, not in `run_test!` block